Where is polars version determined in the build process
I've forked polars and did some modifications to it.
Before publishing it to PyPi (of course under a different name), I want to change it's version number.
However, I was unable to locate when and where in the build process the version number is extracted ? I looked in the various toml files and in the GH Actions.
Any help on this ?
Thanks !

They use the git tags in their build CI/CD to determine the version.

Do you mean py-polars/Cargo.toml? https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/17162/files
